# Как получить исходный js?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Есть js обфусцированный при помощи webpack скрипт 1.261d1b1f.chunk.js и его Source Mapping 1.261d1b1f.chunk.js.map
Как получить исходный код до обфускации?

Comment: обфускацию делают для того, чтобы нельзя было получить исходный код до обфускации

Comment: Для чего тогда Source Mapp?
Выходит что нельзя вообще никак?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/148098/

Comment: Минификацию делают не для этого. В основном, чтобы уменьшить объём для скачивания. При наличии sourceMaps всё прекрасно восстанавливается.

Comment: И как восстановить?